# proper Java package hierarchy?

Tags: java, package

I just started looking at the new FIRST Robotics Java SDK, which includes project generators to build sample robotics programs.

Something I was curious about is the file it generates begins with:

```
package edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.templates;
```

Does this actually make sense? (The library I'm using is from first.wpi.edu, but my project doesn't really have any affiliation with them otherwise.) I'd think that I should want to instead use my own reverse domain for the package specifier.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say your intuition is correct.  I would personally refactor it to be your own package.  Is this just a tutorial project it generated, or is it your project that you are going to be working on.  If this is not a tutorial project, I would be surprised if there is no way to override the package name when it is created.

Comment: It does in fact give a choice for the package name, but that was the default setting and I'm trying to figure out whether to change it.

Answer (score 1):

the idea is that the package names will be globally unique

Answer (score 0):

I would think that it would generate something in a customer supplied package name? Ie: ask the user the package they would like to use.

Does it generate things in more then one package?

Comment: (See comment on Jay's answer.)

Answer (score 0):

It probably does this so it can access "package local" classes.

Answer (score 0):

Using your own reverse domain name makes the most sense.  The [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.1)  (JLS) states that the purpose of the standard package naming structure is to avoid having different published packages with the same name.  By using your own domain name, you ensure that your package will not conflict with other packages published following the standard package naming conventions.  If you use someone else's domain name, you risk a package naming conflict.

The relevant portions of the JLS:

> *Programmers should take steps to avoid the possibility of two published packages having the same name by choosing unique package names for packages that are widely distributed. This allows packages to be easily and automatically installed and catalogued. This section specifies a suggested convention for generating such unique package names. […]*
>
> *If unique package names are not used, then package name conflicts may arise far from the point of creation of either of the conflicting packages. This may create a situation that is difficult or impossible for the user or programmer to resolve. […]*
>
> *You form a unique package name by first having (or belonging to an organization that has) an Internet domain name, such as `oracle.com`. You then reverse this name, component by component, to obtain, in this example, `com.oracle`, and use this as a prefix for your package names, using a convention developed within your organization to further administer package names. […]*